# Angular 2 add route when div scaled

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a angular 2 single page app. On the init screen, I there's a few divs. When a div is clicked, a full screen div scales up and shows the content.

Is there a way of adding url route when div is clicked, like **site.com/article1**, **site.com/article2**...?

I tried using `routerlink`, but that redirects to **site.com/article1** and I can't see the div scaling effect.

Comment: What does `adding url route` mean? perhaps you mean `router.navigate()`

Comment: I mean, when I click article1 div, url will show site.com/article1. I tried with (click)="divClick()" and then router.navigate, but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
changeRoute(route: string): void {
    this._location.go(`articles/${route}`);
}
```

and

```
(click)="changeRoute('article1')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the same view/component to persist even though the route changes, and you want the route to change depending on which article is in focus.

The way to do this is to add a variable to your route, in the route definition like this:

```
{ path: 'articles/:articleNumber' component: ArticleComponent}
```

And when a div is clicked, you add (click) to your div, and make it navigate to the article in the div that was clicked. It could look something like this:

```
<div (click)="navigate('Article1')">/*Div content goes here*/</div>

//TODO: Get article name dynamically, based on the article that was clicked
```

In the component:

```
navigate(article: string): void {
  this.router.navigate(`/articles/${article}`);
}
```

This way, nothing will actually change in the view, even though the path changes.

Comment: Sorry about that. Could you please try `[routerLink]="[`/articles/${article}`]"`instead. Make sure you have `private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,` in the constructor.